# Инкременты и сложения

Tags: java, синтаксис

Вот такой код компилируется в Java без ошибок:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2, b = 3;
        System.out.println(a+++--b);
        System.out.println(a++-++b);
        System.out.println(a---++b);
        System.out.println(a--+--b);
    }
}
```

А вот тут ни одна строчка с `println` не компилируется:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2, b = 3;
        System.out.println(a--+++b); // error: unexpected type
        System.out.println(a++---b); // error: unexpected type
        System.out.println(a+++++b); // error: unexpected type
        System.out.println(a-----b); // error: unexpected type
    }
}
```

Почему так? Ну может последние две ещё сильно сложно разобрать, но первые-то почти такие же как в работающем примере?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю, проблема вот в чём.

Компилятор Java сначала разбивает текст на токены (лексический анализ), а потом пытается понять его значение (синтаксический). Судя по всему, разбиение происходит строго слева направо. При этом `++`, `--`, `+` и `-` являются отдельными токенами.

При чтении первого примера происходит следующее разбиение:

```
a+++--b => a ++ + -- b
```

(поскольку после токена `++` самым длинным возможным токеном является лишь `+`). Это интерпретируется как `(a++) + (--b)`.

Для неработающего случая происходит следующее разбиение:

```
a--+++b => a -- ++ + b
```

— а это невозможно сгруппировать в валидный синтаксис, так как и слева, и справа от `++` находятся выражения, не являющиеся Java-аналогом lvalue.

---

Подтверждение из [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements (§3.5) which, after white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) are discarded, comprise the tokens (§3.5) that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar (§2.3).
>
> The **longest possible translation** is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.

Ниже в документации расположен как раз подходящий пример:

> The input characters `a--b` are tokenized (§3.5) as `a`, `--`, `b`, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` could be part of a grammatically correct program.

Перевод (мой):

> Преобразование потока входных символов и символов окончания строки, получившегося на шаге 2, в последовательность входных элементов(§3.5), которые, после удаления пробелов (§3.6) и комментариев (§3.7), формируют токены (§3.5), являющиеся терминальными символами грамматики языка (§2.3).
>
> На каждом шаге выбирается самое длинный возможный токен, даже если результат в конечном итоге не будет корректной программой, хотя бы даже при другом разбиении на токены получилась корректная программа.
>
> Входные символы `a--b` разбиваются на токены (§3.5) как `a`, `--`, `b`, что не является частью синтаксически корректной программы, хотя разбиение `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` могло бы быть таковым.

Comment: Что третья тема про инкременты и плюсы за сутки? Забавно что в крестах можно таким образом `while(0<--------------------x){}` сделать цикл по модулю 10. А вот в С ошибку бросает(декрементировать можно только lvalue)

Comment: Насколько я помню, в крестах `--х` таки lvalue. А в сишечке, судя по всему, нет.

Comment: @igumnov, это ветром навеяло. Не то чтобы я не знал ответа :-)

Comment: поптавляют это что?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Опечатка :) Спасибо! Имелось в виду «составляют», исправил на более точное «формируют».